# Calculate user formula from account number

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, the first one is dbo.formula

```
Id | Poste  | Calculation | Montant
---+--------+-------------+--------
 1 | Achats | 3801%+381%  | .....
 2 | Tva    | 446%-445%   | ....
 3 | Tiers  | 411%+401%   | ....
```

The second table is dbo.value

```
Compte  | Solde
--------+-------
 380000 | 400.00
 380100 | 500.00
 381100 | 200.00
 381200 | 100.00
4456600 | 100.00
4455400 | 150.00
```

I need to be the result in the first table in field Montant like

```
800.00
50.00
```

I tried a request but it changes only the 3 beginning compute.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, ***please*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: How do these two table relate to each other?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. I understood from your data that you need to calculate the values from the second table to change a column on the first table. But you didn't make that very clear for one to understand. Also your data has no Link between the tables. You should explain how they are linked together. Also, having a string column with string data on it makes things really difficult `380%+381%` you need to parse it first and then do the calculation thats certainly not trivial

Comment: I think I see what you want, but the language barrier is making it hard. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59795218/edit) your question and add the query that you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Join the tables on your conditions and aggregate:

```
select f.ID, f.Poste, sum(v.Solde) total
from formula f inner join value v
on charindex('+' + left(v.Compte, 3) + '%', '+' + f.Calculation) > 0
group by f.ID, f.Poste
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b670ac6d60e76df4460ed25d57a93788).
Results:

```
> ID | Poste  | total  
> -: | :----- | :------
>  1 | Achats | 1200.00
>  2 | Tva    | 250.00
```

Comment: Thank you forpas. If i use 3801% (4digit for exemple) and change the + for - or *, how it will be the query ?